# SpringBoot: how to run tests twice, with two different config files

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am writing a SpringBoot application using a JMS MOM. My application supports two kinds of JMS: EMS and AMQ

My application has many Junit Tests. Of course, whether I use EMS or AMQ the tests are exactly the same and the expected results are also exactly the same. The only difference is the configuration file used.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.yaml")
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class MyTest {

    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("com.mytest")
    static class Application {
    }


    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
    }

}
```

What I would like to be able to do is to run my tests twice, one time with an EMS config and one time with and AMQ config: How should I do?

> FYI, I am using Maven to build my application. A solution based on a maven trick would be  perfectly acceptable for me

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a task for a building tool that you using.

For example, for Maven you can write specific test tasks with different active profiles, something like this:

```
mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=kafka
mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=rabbitmq
mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=activemq
```

and collect necessary properties in files: `application-{profile}.properties`

This articles can help you:

- how to bind a property file to a current active profile: [spring-boot-profile-based-properties](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/)
- mvn profiles:
  [introduction-to-profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)
- mvn different environments:
  [building-for-different-environments](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html)

Comment: Thank you for this answer; I realize that using profiles is the best thing to do. Great.

Now, I need to find a solution to launch automatically my tests twice when I run `mvn clean test`: one with the EMS profile, one other with the AMQ profile.

I opened the following question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340378/springboot-and-maven-how-to-launch-unit-tests-automatically-with-two-profiles