# Springboot and maven: how to launch unit tests automatically with two profiles

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-maven-plugin

> This question is the continuation of question ["SpringBoot: how to run tests twice, with two different config files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134667/springboot-how-to-run-tests-twice-with-two-different-config-files).

I use to compile my project using `mvn clean install`. Doing that, maven also launches my unit tests and I immediately knows whether my development is correct.

I am actually working on a module that embeds a JMS connection. my module supports two JMS buses: EMS and AMQ. *The bus to be used is specified in the configuration of my module*

As a consequence, I need to create two profiles, one for EMS and one for AMQ.

However, when I launch my `mvn clean install` I want that maven launches automatically the tests using the two profiles, not only one; I don't want to have to launch it twice: `mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=ems ; mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=amq`

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the two profiles separated by a comma:

`mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=ems,amq`

And then you'll have two active profiles:

`The following profiles are active: ems,amq`

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a miss-understanding; It seems that when I run my tests with `spring.profiles.active=ems,amq`:

- all tests are launched one time
- both profiles are enabled

What I want is different:

- launch all tests TWO TIMES
- first time with `ems` (and only `ems`) profile enabled
- second time with `amq` (and only `amq`) profile enabled

For the moment, I do not succeed to find a solution; evey clue is welcome

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my issue; a kind of trick based on:

- overloading the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`
- redefining the `run()` method in order to:

  1. call force the use of the first profile
  2. call the origial `run()` method
  3. do the same with the other profile

---

```
public class MultiProfileTestRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner {
...


public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "ems");
    super.run(notifier);

    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "amq");
    super.run(notifier);
}
```

Between both calls to `super.run()` we have to 'force' Spring to reload its context, otherwize the profile change is not taken into account

I did it by using the annotation `@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_CLASS)` on my tests

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify in the `src/test/resources/application.properties` specific properties that apply every time Spring tests are run. Seems cleaner to me than specifying them on Maven command line. For your case :

```
spring.profiles.active=ems,amq
```